# arduino data stream format

Tags: arduino, serial

I wounder what is the format of the serial data stream that usually is sent from computer to arduino through serial connection .
my project use serial connection with arduino to send data from python(pyserial) to arduino , and when I send a string  and I try to print it on LCD it appears but the first  character changes to a chinese or japanese character .

so can any body explane the steam format to understand what is the wrong or what happens .

this is the arduino code and python code I used :
**arduino :**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
    char rd[5] ;
    Serial.readBytesUntil('.', rd, 5);
    Serial.flush();
    Serial.println();
    lcd.print(rd);
}
```

**python**

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',buadrate = 9600)
s.write('est.')
```

**update**
I found through serial monitor that the text is recived correctly but next loop it gives © as a value of rd .

Comment: what happens when you write "est." using the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor?

Comment: Beyond line settings such as no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and the 9600 baud you have set, the format would be up to you to define in your software.  A very common choice is to end messages with a newline.  Right now, likely culprits are either buffer corruption, analog noise, or LCD wiring.  You might try making a test sketch that receives up to a newline and echoes it back on the serial, to get the LCD out of the way.  You could even make a python program that tests the echoing of random strings and logs any failures.

Comment: @geometrikal after I type "est." it appears est on LCD for a second then the first ch>by himself .

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you but I think the problem is not from analog noise all characters are right except first one , I tried to re-send the string more than 20 time an I had the same result . so I don't think it is a noise problem .

Comment: Try put a short delay (100ms) between readbytesuntil and flush. Do different strings give the same corrupted character?

Comment: @geometrikal I tried it but nothing changed .
I tried to put condition/switch to get rid of this character , but It didn't work . this character still appear

Comment: @yahyatawil I think it might be because rd doesn't have a 0x00 byte terminating the string. Try this, change "char rd[5]" to "char rd[6]", after "SerialreadBytesUntil..." put a new line with "rd[5] = 0;"

Comment: actually sorry, if your message e.g. 'est.' is only four bytes long leave char rd[5] as it is, and put the new line with rd[4] = '\0';  (this is shorthand for the null string). I don't think that char rd[5] initialises the bytes to 0 when inside a function... Could be wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings need to be terminated in a '\0' character (typically 0x00) to indicate where the end of the string is.

e.g if you initialise a string like this:

```
char message[] = "hello";
```

It will store 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0' in the memory.

Then in a routine like 'print', the code loops through the string printing each character until it reaches a '\0' character. If that character is not present it will keep going.

I think what is happening in your code is that the 'rd' byte array does not have a terminating  '\0' character. To allow for different length strings try the following:

```
void loop() {
    lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
    //6 bytes long to include '\0'
    char rd[6];
    //Read up to 5 bytes
    byte bytesReceived = Serial.readBytesUntil('.', rd, 5);
    //Set the next byte to '\0' to terminate the string
    rd[bytesReceived] = '\0';
    Serial.flush();
    Serial.println();
    lcd.print(rd);
}
```

Comment: really thank you it is solved know ;) 
I was thinking about termination issue as you mentioned up , but I didn't thought that it was the real problem becuase I know that strings are usally ended with \0 as you said , but It appears it was the problem :)

Comment: @yahyatawil cheers, i am glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the Python function I use for configuring Arduino serial ports. Give it a try:

```
def configure_port(port_id):
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = port_id
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.rtscts = True
    ser.dsrdtr = True
    return ser
```

Usage:

```
port = configure_port("/dev/ttyACM0")
port.open()
```

I think setting `rtscts` and `dsrdtr` to true is what worked for me. The above code at least works for Pro Micros; you didn't specify which Arduino you are using, so this is my best guess.

Comment: I tried what you put but it didn't work , I had the same result (I had the string but the first character is changed after a second).
dose the connection stream adds any bit to data after finishing which changes the ascii number and causes the problem ?

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried calling `Serial.println("Some test text");` to see if it is maybe a problem with your buffering?

Comment: there is no problem with println it works .

Comment: yah!! I found through serial monitor that the text is recived correctly but next loop it gives © as a value of rd .

Comment: Try getting rid of the `readBytesUntil` and `flush` calls, and just use `println`. Or did you already do that?

Comment: I did so , I think the problem is trival now and can be solved by add conditions , I will try to add some conditions . thanks very much .

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to geometrikal, the problem was :  arduino recives a not ended string with \0 , and when the next loop comes it goes to the **position (5,1)** which is the first character of the printed string on the screen and arduino prints over it the default value of the variable **rd** if nothing is recived .